# SimpleXML Java add class as element

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

In my `Android` project, I have two `XML` files like these:

```
<request>
  <target>www.facebook.com</target>
  <packetsize>32</packetsize>
  <timeout>4</timeout>
  ...
</request>
```

and

```
<response>
  <target>www.facebook.com</target>
  <packetsize>32</packetsize>
  <timeout>4</timeout>
  ...
</request>
```

Both files have the same elements, but different root nodes. Using the `SimpleXML` framework, I want to create a new class called PinResponse as a container for all elements from the XML files for reusing/changing the attributes of a response. For this, I want to reference the class in my XML model classes as element.

PinResponse class:

```
@Element
public class PinResponse {

    @Element(name = "target")
    private String target;

    @Element(name = "packetsize")
    private int packetSize;

    @Element(name = "timeout")
    private int timeout;

    ...
}
```

XML Model class:

```
@Root(name = "request")
public class PingResponseData {

    @Element
    private PinResponse pinResponse;

    public PinResponse getPinResponse() {
        return pinResponse;
    }
}
```

but I always get an ElementException:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'target' does not have a match in class
```

How can I add the PinResponse class as element to my XML model classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kris Larsons [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35990233/4779830) helped me to solve my problem, this is how my final solution looks like now:

Base class: (protected access to use elements in subclass)

```
public abstract class Ping {

    @Element(name = "target")
    protected String target;

    @Element(name = "packetsize")
    protected int packetSize;

    @Element(name = "timeout")
    protected int timeout;

    ...(getter/setter)
}
```

Request subclass:

```
@Root(name = "request")
public class PingRequest extends PingRequestResponse { 

    public PingRequest(Ping ping) {
            this.target = ping.getTarget();
            this.packetsize = ping.getPacketsize();
            this.timeout = ping.getTimeout();
            ...
}
```

Response subclass:

```
@Root(name = "response")
public class PingResponse extends PingRequestResponse { 
            //empty as it has the same elements, if it would have additional fields, they would be added here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally the way you would do this would be something like this:

```
public abstract class PingRequestResponse {

    @Element(name = "target")
    private String target;

    @Element(name = "packetsize")
    private int packetSize;

    @Element(name = "timeout")
    private int timeout;

    ...
}

@Root(name = "request")
public class PingRequest extends PingRequestResponse { }

@Root(name = "response")
public class PingResponse extends PingRequestResponse { }
```

However, I haven't worked with SimpleXML enough to know if the annotations will work correctly within subclasses like this.

Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try that!